# specifying two models/arrays in a for each loop?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I know a for each loop focuses on one array usually, however I'm new to Umbraco and I'm wondering if this is possible?

My code is as follows:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var feature in homePage.CSSHomepages.Where("featuredPage"))
        {
            <div class="3u">
                <!-- Feature -->
                <section class="is-feature">
                    <a href="@feature.Url" class="image image-full"><img src="@feature.Image" alt="" /></a>
                    <h3><a href="@feature.Url">@feature.Name</a></h3>
                    @Umbraco.Truncate(feature.BodyText, 100)
                </section>
                <!-- /Feature -->
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

This currently displays one featured page, however I'm trying to also display a featured page from "HTMLHomepages", too.

I've tried the following code to no avail:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var feature in homePage.CSSHomepages.Where("featuredPage") & homePage.HTMLHomepages.Where("featuredPage"))
        {
            <div class="3u">
                <!-- Feature -->
                <section class="is-feature">
                    <a href="@feature.Url" class="image image-full"><img src="@feature.Image" alt="" /></a>
                    <h3><a href="@feature.Url">@feature.Name</a></h3>
                    @Umbraco.Truncate(feature.BodyText, 100)
                </section>
                <!-- /Feature -->
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

But as I expected, I get runtime errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: concat the two arrays and then do the foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime error you receive is not umbraco related.
You have a single &-sign.  This does not exists in the razor language.
You should at least use `&&` which means AND. 
However in this case you don't want to use and AND operator, but an OR operator: `||`.  This all would be true if you are checking something in an `if` statement.

Here you are looping through an array. That means that you need to concatenate the two arrarys before looping through them.  Normally you get two `IEnumerable`'s from the Umbraco API.  To join two IEnumerables together you could use the [Concat (see MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function.

What I would do:

```
@{
   var featureList = homePage.CSSHomepages.Where("featuredPage").Concat(homePage.HTMLHomepages.Where("featuredPage"))
}

<div class="row">
  @foreach( var feature in featureList) {
     // your existing code
  }
</div>
```